# IE browser block UI when making ajax call to server side code while showing spinner

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I am using jquery, mvc in my application
I have situation where i want to show spinner/ loading image when ajax call to server side code is in progress. so for that i made async call as shown below to server side code but on internet explorer its blocking UI and loading image does not show spinning.

below is my ajax call code

```
 function GetDetails(){
 $('.spinner').show();
  var requestObject = {
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
              $('.spinner').hide();
               result = data;
             }
      };
   }
```

But before i get response from ajax loader image get freeze and don`t show it as loading.
It looks like actually the IE browser is blocking UI. So can anyone helm me to solve the problem, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clear the IE browser cache and cookie, or restart the IE browser and the computer.

Since can't reproduce the problem using your code, I have created a sample using the following code, it works well on my side (using Chrome, Microsoft Edge and IE 11 browser), you could refer to it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnGet").click(function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                global: false,
                type: "GET",
                url: "https://api.ipify.org/?format=json",
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $(".modal").show();
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $(".modal").hide();
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                data: "{}",
                success: function (r) {
                    $("#lblIPAddress").html("IP Address: " + r.ip);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script> 
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 10pt;
    }

    .modal {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 999;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: Black;
        filter: alpha(opacity=60);
        opacity: 0.6;
        -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    }

    .center {
        z-index: 1000;
        margin: 300px auto;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 130px;
        background-color: White;
        border-radius: 10px;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-opacity: 1;
    }

        .center img {
            height: 128px;
            width: 128px;
        }
</style>

<input type="button" id="btnGet" value="Get IP Address" />
<br />
<br />
<span id="lblIPAddress"></span>
<div class="modal" style="display: none">
    <div class="center"> 
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOAYl.gif" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The result like this:

[image]

Reference: [Show Loading (Busy) Indicator (Spinner) with Overlay with jQuery AJAX example](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Show-Loading-Busy-Indicator-Spinner-with-Overlay-with-jQuery-AJAX-example.aspx)